# Custom new form with branching in Survey list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, survey

I created Survey list where I have questions with branching, I created custom new form for that survey where I will make some customization.

My question is, How can I activate branching in Custom new form?
By default when I create custom new form in SPD, I get all questions at same time.

Answer (score 2):

"Branching Logic" is designed for Survey list. You may want to customize the regular list form (NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx) with InfoPath 2010, then use the "Formating" rule to hide the fields according to other fields different value, here are some related posts,

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8517e1d0-85ab-4b0c-a48b-ee04d31ea958

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg180738.aspx

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKYBkr1a4sA

Thanks

Comment: I cannot use InfoPath.